Is it possible to create multiple compressed resources with maven?
I was working on a Maven mini project in which at some point I need to create multiple compressed files in gzip (.jgz). For this I used the maven-assembly plugin, but I can only create one archive at a time.
pom.xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>compress-jgz</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <filter><filter>./doj.properties</filter></filters>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/gzip.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <finalName>mainJs.js</finalName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>

</plugin>

and my descriptor
<assembly

xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">

<id>gzip</id>

<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<formats>

    <format>gzip</format>

</formats>

<fileSets>

<!--  

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${release-dir}</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>"${pluginMainClassName}.css"</include> 
            <!- - //nothing here  - ->
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>${webcontentdir}</outputDirectory> 
    </fileSet> 
    -->

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${release-dir}</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>${pluginMainClassName}.js</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${webcontentdir}/${dojoPackage}</outputDirectory> 
        <!-- the compressed file only goes to the target directory -->

    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
</assembly> 

I wanted to know o=if there was a way to manipule maven assembly plugin in order to create several compressed files at once instead of having to do multiple executions.
Also I'm not sure I f I understand what the outputdirectory refers to.
